# Is meeting people on the street the only way to make friends?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, streetpass

I want to meet more people/have more Miis in my 3DS Mii plaza.

Is there another way (other than StreetPass) to meet new Miis? While StreetPass is fine, I don't meet people very often.

I know the Wii has Friend Codes. Does the 3DS have anything similar?

Comment: I lol-d after reading the title

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The friend function is unrelated to the streetpass plaza. One person on my friends list has only appeared once in streetpass plaza - which was from when we set it up to begin with.

Miis can come to the plaza from playing multiplayer with them in certain games, like Mario Kart 7. Note that these can not be used for the streetpass games.

Other than that, you need to meet them "on the street", as far as I can tell.

Comment: So even if I use someone's Friend Code, they won't appear in the Plaza? :(

Comment: The one thing I can say for sure is that they don't reappear from it. I had already gotten the streetpass with the friend I have on If you really want to populate it quickly (ignoring the streetpass games) the mario kart 7 method is by far the most efficient - possibly with the exception of visiting nintendo of japan/america/europe offices. (Presumably a lot of people there would have them.)

Comment: What is this Mario Kart 7 method you speak of? to get more friends in the plaza?

Comment: Yes. Any player you play with online in mario kart 7 will have his mii appear in street pass plaza. They will count towards the achievements for number of miis in the plaza, but will not be usable in the games.

Comment: Please note that with the most recent 3DS system update, Nintendo Zones will relay StreetPasses, so that two users don't need to be at the same place at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to add Miis to the StreetPass-Plaza are special Miis. You can scan the QR-codes, to get the Miis and can send them to the plaza. They cannot be used for puzzles/find-mii though.

Resident evil special miis: http://www.nintendolife.com/news/2011/09/get_your_special_resident_evil_miis_now

Some other Miis: http://streetpassberlin.wordpress.com/2012/01/16/mii-mit-goldenen-hosen/

Scan the QR-codes with the Mii-Maker. That works directly from computer-screen. You can send them afterwards to the Mii-Plaza, but they are only at one place at once.

Answer (score 1):

There are friend codes in the 3DS as well, you can access the friend utility from the main screen by tapping the orange smiley icon. You can add friends locally by connecting consoles via WiFi or by inputting their friend codes.
On the Wii, Miis roamed between friend consoles as well so I believe this will also be the case.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to meet people on the 3DS is either using streetpass or entering your friends friend-code.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a special Mii will come via Spotpass.

Answer (score 0):

You can also go to special wifi hotspots like best buy to get streetpass tags from people who have been there recently without having to ever come near them. You can find a nearby location with [this map](http://www.nintendo.com/3ds/nintendozone#find-a-nintendo-zone-location).

Answer (score -2):

No. Get someone that you know who has a 3DS. Ask them for their name and code. Go to the top of your 3DS and click on the smiley face. Go to register friend. It's gonna say internet and local. Click on internet. Put in the code first, then the name. For it to work, the other person has to put in your code and name too.

Comment: While this does give me friends, it doesn't add people to the Mii Plaza.